Angular Frontend and Springboot API Backend Azure hosting
I am currently designing an app with Angular Front-end and Springboot API services in backend, what is the most cost effective way to host this application in Azure Cloud? As far as I know, we can use App service for API but how about the Front-end, I saw that it can be deployed in App Service as well but what I'm not clear is the communication since it will be in separate App Service. Say for example FE sends the request to BE so we will just get the url given by BE from azure , is it that straight forward?
Please do not mark as duplicate as some of the questions I saw with related technology is way old, I believe Azure is updated since then. Thanks a lot.

I'd suggest using Azure Static Web Apps.
Cons:

Vendor lockin as this will not be as portable as using containers.
You might need to refactor your Java codebase to work as an Azure Function.

Pros

Super simple management and lowest operating costs.
Adding extra layers of security will be a relatively easy task.
You will get a free SSL certificate (yay).
Seamless integration with GitHub actions.
Supports Blue/Green deployments (I think).

You can read more about Azure Static Web Apps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/overview

Hi Kane thank you for your suggestion, you mean the api cannot be in app service hosted in azure? it should be azure function?

You can most definitely use an Azure App Service, but an Azure Static Web Apps (which use Azure Functions as their API endpoint of choice) is a much better/cheaper/simpler option.
